# Yahoo Pipes, configure a pipe at runtime with as many URLs as needed

Tags: yahoo-pipes, aggregators

I'm having trouble to do something that I though it would be a 5 minutes thing.

I want to create a Pipe that accepts **at runtime** as many URLs as needed. I know how I can combine many URLs within the editor, but I want a Pipe that anybody can configure to their needs.

I thought I could use the URL Input module within a Loop, but it's not possible. Then I thought about using a Text input module and link it to the URL builder but that's not what I want either.

I have to be missing something very obvious here.

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to accept an external list of URLs, i.e. a URL that contains the parameter URLs. Then you accept the source URL as parameter of your pipe.

I created [this sample](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4gMMJnb73RGt30tTPxJ3AQ) to get your started, it merges the feeds listed in a URL.

Another option is to take a string parameter, then tokenize it on spaces, commas, or other separator, then do whatever you need to do with each URL. [Sample pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=KGOw7qn73RGup0S4rbQIDg).

Comment: That is very close but now exactly what I wanted. It works as long people can host a file with the list of URLs, but for many people that might not be an option or be too much of a hassle.

However I'll accept the answer if nobody else comes with something better.

Thanks!

Comment: I just added another option, it's not as flexible but is simpler